# USB switch controlled by GPIO

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, gpio

I would like to find a USB extension cord with a switch, a bit like the picture below, but instead of a manual switch, I would like to control it by GPIO of RPi.

I thought it would be easy to find but I tried many keywords in English and French and couldn't find something already built. Should I create it myself with a transistor on the Vcc of the USB (I don't know if it that simple)?

[image: USB extension cord with manual switch]

[EDIT]
The reason why I need that is, sometimes I got a problem with my motor driver that is connected in USB to the RPi. The only solution we have to reset it is to unplug and replug the USB cable. That's is why I would do it softwarely and then be able to restart everything from a script.

That's why I don't know if just opening the Vcc is enough or should I open the 4 wires of the USB cable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you hoping that the data lines will work when you have the power on or are you using this only to power a 5 V device? (The external device may not like seeing voltage on the data lines when the +5 V is switched off. That's why the +5 and GND pins are longer than the data lines so that the device is fully powered before the data lines connect.)

Comment: It's not that simple, also I think you're trying to solve a problem with this that has an easier solution (which is why you're not finding any products). You'll probably want to describe the purpose of what you're intending to build (by **editing** your question, don't just comment), which will allow experts to advise on what you need to do to achieve that switch functionality / purpose.

Comment: Hello, I'll edit my post. For a quick answer: I'm hoping the device to work like if I unplug the USB. For that I'm not sure if just cutting the power lane is enough